# "Object reference not set to an instance of object" error in callback

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, push-notification, ihttpasynchandler

I am using IHttpAsyncHandler and XMLHTTPRequest to push messages to client with the help of following URL: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42734/Using-IHttpAsyncHandler-and-XMLHttpRequest-to-push
but I make some changes, actually this example based to one client only and I have to send messages to multiple clients so I make these changes

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
        var recipient = context.Request["recipient"]; 
        lock (_obj)
        {               
            string[] totalfrnds = ("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20").Split(',');//<- This is just an example for many clients

            foreach (var a in totalfrnds)
            {
                var handle = MyAsyncHandler.Queue.Find(q => q.SessionId == a);//<- check who's client is online or not

                if (handle != null)
                {
                    handle.Message = context.Request["message"];

                    handle.SetCompleted(true);
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

[image: Error Snapshot]

Now I have two problems

1. How to resolve this type of error? This is not a permanent error, it occurs randomly.
2. What is the limit of asynchronous thread in W3wp.exe, as when it exceeds 25 request it can't open next request and I have to reset the IIS to start again the application.

Answer (score 1):

> How to resolve this type of error?

You have a [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition) - change your `SetCompleted` method to take a copy of `Callback` at the time of invocation e.g.

```
var handler = Callback;
if (isCompleted && handler != null)
{
    handler(this);
}
```

---

> What is the limit of asynchronous threads in W3wp.exe

This is configured in the `machine.config` file on your server, specifically the **maxWorkerThreads** element in the [`<processModel>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) section, according to the docs the default is **20**:

> Configures the maximum amount of worker threads to be used for the process on a per-CPU basis. For example, if this value is 25 on a single-processor server, ASP.NET uses the runtime APIs to set the process limit to 25. On a two-processor server, the limit is set to 50. **The default is 20**. The value of maxWorkerThreads must be equal to or greater than the minFreeThread attribute setting in the  configuration section.

Comment: thanks for the answer. can u explain me briefly with proper example.

Comment: @ankitGupta "*give me a proper solution*" - not quite the correct way of asking for help! Besides I *have* gave you a proper solution.

Comment: actually i am trying to solve this error from last few days, but nothing find solution that's why i am asking u for the solution.  i didn't understand the solution. can u plz describe it

Comment: @ankitGupta you asked 2 questions - which to the best of my knowledge I have answered - I don't know what else you want me to tell you as your question hasn't changed.

Comment: Your Solution is not working. Again the same error be appeared.

Comment: @ankitGupta So your still getting the NRE with the code I suggested? Could you elaborate a little more?